# Counting the number of functions

Tags: combinatorics, functions, equivalence-relations

Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of the set $\Bbb Z$ for all integers, and let $\mathscr F$ denote the set of all functions $f:A\rightarrow B.$ Assume $A = \{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{1,2,...,n\}$ where $n\ge 2$ is a fixed integer.

Define a relation $R$ on $\mathscr F$ by : for any $f,g \in \mathscr F$,  $\;fRg\;$ if and only if $f - g$ is a constant function (i.e. there is a constant $c$ so that $f(x) - g(x) =c$ for all $x\in A$).

(b) Find the number of functions $f \in \mathscr F$ so that $[f]= \{f\}$

So  this means I need to find the number of functions so that $1$ and $n$ are in the range. So for example $f = \{(1,n),(2,1),(3,n-2$ choices$)\}$, so I have 1 choice for the first 2 and n-2 choices for the third. So $1 \times 1 \times (n-2) = n$ functions. But I have to consider the permutations too so it would be $3! \times n$ But this would be true if the functions were one-to-one. What if they are not?

(c) Find the number of distinct equivalence classes $[f]$ of $R$.

For this one I need to find the number of functions so that $1$ is in the range right? so functions that have $f(x)=1$. For example $f = \{(1,1),(2,n$ choices$),(n$ choices$)\}$ and taking the permutations into consideration it would be $3! \times n^2$?

Comment: Sorry, thanks for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(b) It’s probably simplest to subtract the functions that you don’t want from the $3^n$ functions in $\mathscr{F}$. There are $(n-2)^3$ functions from $A$ to $B$ whose ranges contain neither $1$ nor $n$. There are $(n-1)^3$ whose ranges do not contain $1$, so there are $(n-1)^3-(n-2)^3$ whose ranges contain $n$ but not $1$. Similarly, there are $(n-1)^3-(n-2)^3$ whose ranges contain $1$ but not $n$. That’s a total of

$$(n-2)^3+2\left((n-1)^3-(n-2)^3\right)=2\cdot(n-1)^3-(n-2)^3=n^3-6n+6$$

functions whose ranges are missing at least one of the numbers $1$ and $n$, so there are $$n^3-\left(n^3-6n+6\right)=6n-6=6(n-1)$$ functions $f\in\mathscr{F}$ such that $[f]=\{f\}$.

(c) Yes, every equivalence class contains exactly one function whose range contains $1$. Here it’s definitely easiest to count the functions whose ranges **don’t** contain $1$, and I already did that in answering (b).

Comment: Wouldn't it be $n^3$ instead of $3^n$? You have $n$ choices for each element in $A$ so $n*n*n = n^3$

Comment: Just double checked an yeah, the number of functions from set A to B is $B^A$, so your answer is correct just the exponents and bases are exchanged

Comment: @crazymao: Thanks! Yes, I apparently interchanged $A$ and $B$ mentally when writing the answer.

Comment: With that in mind the answer should be $6n - 6$ which makes the guys in the other answer correct with $3!n - 6$

Comment: @user60334: Please note the correction to my answer: I mentally interchanged $A$ and $B$ when I wrote it, so all of the exponentiations were the wrong way around.

Answer (score 1):

b) If the functions were one-to-one then f={(1,n),(2,1),(3,[n-2, not 1 or n, choices])
so 3! x (n-2)

By allowing the third element in the domain to be 1, n, or anything else, you are not restricting your count to one-to-one functions. Eg. f={(1,n),(2,1),(3,n)} is not one-to-one.

I think that 3! x n would count some functions more than once though.

Is this for Sands' class by chance? Awesome coincidence otherwise.

Comment: You are right, it should be $n-2$, I think $3!(n-2)+$(the number of functions that are not one-to-one and have $1$ and $n$ in their range) should be the answer.

Comment: @user60334 I came at it from the opposite direction but landed in the same place. 3!(n) - 6 also works. So does 3!(n-1)

Comment: that might be wrong because $n \ge 2$ when I dont consider that I get the same answer as you which is $3!(n-2)+6$ but if you consider that $n \ge 2$ then I get $3!(n-2) + 3$ so yours would be $3!n-3$

Comment: because for functions that are not one-to-one and have $1$ and $n$ in their range, if $n\ge 2$ then you have $1$ choice for what  $f(x)$ is which is just $n$ so you have $3 perms \times 1 \times 1 \times 1$

Comment: sorry, actually it would be $3!(n)-9$

Comment: Hmmm, I drew out the possibilities for n=2 and n=3 and it seemed to work. Let me look over what you wrote again...

Comment: Actually, I think I was mistaken. You still have 2 choices either $1$ or $n$ so it would be $3\times2$ and yours is correct I think.

Comment: n = 3... (not one-to one) 1 1 3, 1 3 1, 3 1 1, | 1 3 3, 3 1 3, 3 3 1 | (are one-to-one) 1 2 3, 1 3 2, 2 1 3, 2 3 1, 3 2 1, 3 1 2

Comment: Yeah, yours is correct I think.

Comment: Cool... I really didn't want to have to go back and tackle that again. For the last question: I think the answer is either n or n-1. n because: if g(a) = 1 and h(b) = 1, g = h. Of course if g(a) = 1 = h(a), c = 0 so g = h. Then the possibilities for the range of a function f are 1, 2, ..., n. So n equivalence classes. n-1 is just a hunch right now...